# Pandas df read every row, return SQL query with a new column in df

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe as df and I want to query each row of `df['item']` that will return corresponding `item_description` from a SQL Server database and populate df with columns 'id', 'qty', 'item', 'item_description'

```
|  id | qty  | item |
+-----+------+------+
| 001 |  700 | CB04 |
| 002 |  500 |      |
| 003 | 1500 | AB01 |
```

I was doing the following:

```
query = "select item_description from item_book WHERE item in {}".format(tuple(df['item']))
```

and return it as a df with

```
pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
```

Results:

```
| item_description |
+------------------+
| apple            |
| orange           |
```

I was planning to join the two dfs together, doing this may not work since I have an empty value in 2nd row of df and my query returned only two rows.

Is there a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SQL query to return both the item and item_description columns to give you a dataframe something like this:

```
   item item_description
0  CB04            apple
1  AB01           orange
```

Then you have a common column that can be used to join the two dataframes with the `merge` function:

```
pd.merge(original_df, desc_df, on="item", how="left")
```

We could leave out the `on` argument because there is only one column in each dataframe with the same name and pandas would figure out that's what they should be joined on.  But the `how` argument is necessary to preserve any rows from the first dataframe (*left*-most argument to `merge`) that don't have a corresponding row in the second dataframe.  The result is:

```
   id   qty  item item_description
0   1   700  CB04            apple
1   2   500                    NaN
2   3  1500  AB01           orange
```

You can read more about merging in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).